# Java 8 stream - sum of objects

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Let's say I have a list of objects implementing below interface:

```
public interface Summable<T> {
    T add(T o1);
}
```

Let's say I have also some class which is able to sum these objects:

```
public class Calculator<T extends Summable<T>> {
    public T sum(final List<T> objects) {
        if (null == objects) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Ups, list of objects cannot be null!");
        }
        T resultObject = null;
        for (T object : objects) {
            resultObject = object.add(resultObject);
        }
        return resultObject;
   }
}
```

How can I achieve the same using Java 8 streams?

I'm playing around a custom Collector, but couldn't figure out some neat solution.

Comment: It looks like it should probably be `public interface Summable<T extends Summable<T>>`

Comment: Not necessarily, Calculator has it and it is enough I suppose.

Comment: Not directly related to the question but in your example,`resultObject` will always be null.

Comment: Only in first iteration, but what's the point? Have you some better idea how can I write it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What you have is a [reduction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Reduction):

```
return objects.stream().reduce(T::add).orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list.stream().reduce(Summable::add);

interface Summable {
    Summable add(Summable o1);
}
```