# How to sum values in a Map with a stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, generics

I want the equivalent of this with a stream:

```
public static <T extends Number> T getSum(final Map<String, T> data) {
    T sum = 0;
    for (String key: data.keySet())
        sum += data.get(key);
    return sum;
}
```

This code doesn't actually compile because 0 cannot be assigned to type T, but you get the idea.

Comment: You simply cannot do this because Java doesn't accept operator overloading for classes.

Comment: I don't get the idea. What do you want the answer to be, a `T` or a primitive type like `int`?

Comment: @pbabcdefp Integer, Double, or it could be int, or double

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873215/can-i-do-arithmetic-operations-on-the-number-baseclass. If generic arithmetic is your goal you will basically need to find a library or write one.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here's another way to do this:

```
int sum = data.values().stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum);
```

(For a sum to just `int`, however, Paul's answer does less boxing and unboxing.)

As for doing this *generically*, I don't think there's a way that's much more convenient.

We could do something like this:

```
static <T> T sum(Map<?, T> m, BinaryOperator<T> summer) {
    return m.values().stream().reduce(summer).get();
}

int sum = MyMath.sum(data, Integer::sum);
```

But you always end up passing the summer. `reduce` is also problematic because it returns `Optional`. The above `sum` method throws an exception for an empty map, but an empty sum should be 0. Of course, we could pass the 0 too:

```
static <T> T sum(Map<?, T> m, T identity, BinaryOperator<T> summer) {
    return m.values().stream().reduce(identity, summer);
}

int sum = MyMath.sum(data, 0, Integer::sum);
```

Comment: there's also no generic solution to sum heterogeneous stream of Number (AtomicInteger, AtomicLong, BigDecimal, BigInteger, Byte, Double,...) and possibly custom types

Comment: The arguments for `Integer.sum` are both `int`, so in the first bit you're going to have to get from `T` to `int` somehow. I think the solution to the `Optional` problem is to make the method accept a zero value and use `orElse`.

Comment: @Radiodef Lambdas do unboxing, yes, but they won't unbox a `Number` to an `int`...

Answer (score 98):

You can do this:

```
int sum = data.values().stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum();
```

Comment: Awesome! is there any way to make it generic?

Comment: @Jay You can pass the mapper and summer in. You'd end up with something like `MyMath.sum(map, Number::intValue, Integer::sum)` and the summer is a reduce operation. That's not much better so not really.

Comment: @Jay It's already generic in the sense that `T` is any type extending `Number`. If you mean, is there any way to make it give an `int` or a `double` etc, the answer is no as primitive types in java need to be dealt with separately.

Comment: @Jay 'Generic' means to decide what field of `Number` you want to sum up (`intValue`, `doubleValue`, `longValue`)?

Comment: @Jay See this answer for how to do a reduction over a stream to get a generalized sum: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30019328/3973077

Comment: @isnot2bad I wanted to wrap it in a function like T sum(Map<String, T>map) {}, but this is pretty close

Comment: @Jay As others already stated: That's not possible. Can't be, as `Map<String, Number>` would be a legal argument, which could contain a mix of `Integer`, `Double`, `Long`... as values.

Comment: @pbabcdefp good find! I guess I can do it if I create a class with an add method

Comment: What you'd have to do is make an interface `Summable` as in the question I link to and then make classes implement that interface for each number type (`WrappedInt`, `WrappedDouble` etc).

Comment: @pbabcdefp mapping to int is not a good idea for collection of Long or BigDecimal or Double, maybe correct your answer, as it's now too misleading

Comment: @harshtuna Most people don't bother to explain downvotes, so I appreciate that. I think the question was more about how to translate summing using a `for` loop into `Stream`s, and my answer does that. I agree a more generic approach, returning the same type as the numbers in the collection would be better, and I explain how to do that in the comments above. However the answer I give is not completely useless; for integral types `BigInteger`, `Integer`, `Long` etc it returns the sum modulo `2^32`. For `Float`, `Double` and `BigDecimal` I agree there isn't much point.

Comment: @pbabcdefp for-loop to streams is easy, that would be simply duplicate which does not deserve any answer. Generic Number handling is the challenge here.

Comment: @harshtuna But since we can't really do generic number handling we are suggesting alternatives. : ) It's fine if you want to downvote it I guess but we know we are suggesting alternatives.

Comment: @Radiodef 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30089778/4770813) worked for me but this one shows ***incompatible types: invalid method reference \n incompatible types: integer cannot be converted to String \n The type of mapToInt(ToIntFunction<? super T>) is erroneous \n where T is a type-variable: \n T extends Object declared in interface Stream***. I'm just returning the whole line in a `public int` method. My map's key is a reference to one of my java classes and the value is an `Integer`. Please help, thanks

Answer (score 5):

```java
Integer sum = intMap.values().stream().mapToInt(d-> d).sum();
```

Get the `HashMap.values` method to Stream and collect `mapToIn` with lambda expression ending with aggregation sum method.

Answer (score 2):

For Doubles you can use this simply.

```
Double sum = myMap.values().stream().mapToDouble(d -> d).sum();
```

works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
int creditAmountSum = result.stream().map(e -> e.getCreditAmount()).reduce(0, (x, y) -> x + y);
```

Comment: `(x, y) -> x + y` can also be written as `Long::sum` ;)