# How to sum with Stream api?

Tags: java, sum, java-stream

I'm trying to find the sum of hours between two dates in each segment.

Segment:

```
class Segment {
    private final LocalDateTime departureDate;

    private final LocalDateTime arrivalDate; 
    //..getter setter
```

Flight:

```
class Flight {
    private final List<Segment> segments;
   //.. getter setter
```

I try to do so, but it is not compile. What is problem here?

```
int sum = flightList.forEach(flight -> {
    flight.getSegments().stream().mapToInt(segment -> (int) ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(segment.getDepartureDate(), segment.getArrivalDate())).sum();
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't that `int sum = ` go _inside_ the loop? `forEach()` returns `void` and thus this can't compile. Also you probably want a sum per flight, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sum values in a Map with a stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30089469/how-to-sum-values-in-a-map-with-a-stream)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd stream the `flightList`, then `flatMap` it to get a list of `Segment`s, and then map them to the hours between departure and arrival and sum. Note that `ChronoUnit.between` returns a `long`, not an `int` though:

```java
long sum = 
    flightList.stream()
              .flatMap(f -> f.getSegments().stream())
              .mapToLong(s -> ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(
                                  s.getDepartureDate(), s.getArrivalDate()))
              .sum();
```

Comment: OP ask question _What is problem here?_ I think if you add an explanation for that then it will be more helpful, IMHO ofcourse.

Comment: @Eklavya Sorry, my English is not very good

Answer (score 1):

The `.forEach()` operation does not return anything, so you cannot assign it to the sum variable. What you need here is the `flatMap()` operation:

```java
flightList.stream().flatMap(flight -> flight.getSegments().stream())
.mapToInt(segment -> (int) ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(segment.getDepartureDate(), segment.getArrivalDate())
.sum();
```